# Script won't execute on crontab

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script which executes manually:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -t cifs //192.168.138.18/Shared_Drive /mnt/share -o username=user,password=guest
```

But `sudo crontab -e` doesn't execute it. I tried:

```
@reboot /home/user/startup.sh
@reboot sh /home/user/startup.sh
@reboot bash -l /home/user/startup.sh
@reboot /bin/bash /home/user/startup.sh
```

Nothing works. Permits are:
`-rwxr-x--x 1 user user`

Comment: Do you have email set up on the system? Do you get an email with the cronjob output? Any errors in that? Silly question, but just in case: do you run it manually as the same user? Can you use the full path to `mount` in the script?

Comment: manually i have to sudo it. How to make crontab sudo it as well?

Comment: But if you are just mounting something, why not put the whole thing in `/etc/fstab` instead?

Comment: didn't think of that) But anyway, what could be the problem?

Comment: 99% of the time, when something doesn't work from cron it's an environment issue. 

Pipe the stderr to another file and see what the problem is. Add `env > env.txt` and run it manually and via cron and see what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -e` doesn't execute scheduled command, it opens your crontab rules file in an editor

The command will then be executed by `cron` itself on the specified schedule.  (If the rule is written correctly.  If you want help checking that then include the cron rule.)

Also note that the `crontab` command man page says

> Note that su(8) can confuse `crontab` and that if you are running inside of su(8) you should always use the `-u` option for safety's sake

So you should run `sudo crontab -u root -e`